# Use multi-lined string in preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

i have the following problem: I try to find a part of a website using preg_match:

```
preg_match("|<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5 WIDTH=1280 HEIGHT=50>
<TR VALIGN=TOP>
<TD WIDTH=1280 BGCOLOR=WHITE>
<FONT COLOR=BLACK SIZE=2>
This
is
a
test
</FONT>
</TR>
</TABLE>
|",$website,$matches);
```

It works fine... But the value of the table (in this case "This is a test") changes every day so i tried to do it like this:

```
preg_match("|<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5 WIDTH=1280 HEIGHT=50>
<TR VALIGN=TOP>
<TD WIDTH=1280 BGCOLOR=WHITE>
<FONT COLOR=BLACK SIZE=2>
(.*)
</FONT>
</TR>
</TABLE>
|",$website,$matches);
```

But now the return value of the function is 0, so it didn't found any matches. Only when i try this it works again:

```
preg_match("|<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5 WIDTH=1280 HEIGHT=50>
<TR VALIGN=TOP>
<TD WIDTH=1280 BGCOLOR=WHITE>
<FONT COLOR=BLACK SIZE=2>
(.*)
(.*)
(.*)
(.*)
</FONT>
</TR>
</TABLE>
|",$website,$matches);
```

So my problem is now: How can I find the part even if the value of the table has 4 lines today and 6 tomorrow for example (i never know^^)

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `s` modifier to match over multiple lines, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
...
|s",$website,$matches);
```

However, regex is not the best way to parse html, you'd better use something like PHP Simple HTML DOM parser.

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine! :) I will have a look at Simple HTML DOM Parser!

Answer (score 1):

For Trace html sources, [HTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) class is better than `preg_match`, and it is clean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `s` (aka [*dotall*](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)) modifier to allow `.` to match newline characters:

```
preg_match("|<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5 WIDTH=1280 HEIGHT=50>
<TR VALIGN=TOP>
<TD WIDTH=1280 BGCOLOR=WHITE>
<FONT COLOR=BLACK SIZE=2>
(.*?)
</FONT>
</TR>
</TABLE>
|s",$website,$matches);
 ^
```

You should also use `.*?` to make the match non-greedy. Otherwise, if the website contains multiple tables formatted like this, you might match from the beginning of one table to the end of the other.

Comment: Also good to recommended the use of `(\s*?)` rather than placing new lines in your search subject, such that it ignores spaces/tabs that can show up in formatted html.

Comment: This code seems to be intended for a very specific HTML layout. If you want to be more flexible, you should use an HTML DOM parser rather than a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This works - (Just added a condition to include \n as well.)

```
preg_match("/<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5 WIDTH=1280 HEIGHT=50>
<TR VALIGN=TOP>
<TD WIDTH=1280 BGCOLOR=WHITE>
<FONT COLOR=BLACK SIZE=2>
((?:.|\n)*?)
<\/FONT>
<\/TR>
<\/TABLE>
/",$website,$matches);
print_r($matches);

//OUTPUT:
Array
(
    [0] => <TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5 WIDTH=1280 HEIGHT=50>
            <TR VALIGN=TOP>
            <TD WIDTH=1280 BGCOLOR=WHITE>
            <FONT COLOR=BLACK SIZE=2>
            This
            is
            a
            test
            </FONT>
            </TR>
            </TABLE>

    [1] => This
        is
        a
        test
)
```